# How to add a tag or id to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

This is my pager adapter.

```
public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public PagerAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return (SherlockFragment) Fragment.instantiate(mContext,
                info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.d("Tab position selected = ", "" + tab.getPosition());
        // Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

How can i add a tag or an id to the fragments in each tab. So that i can access them later.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use override for this method and apply your custom fragment,

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        fragment = new Fragment1();
    else (position == 1)
        fragment = new Fragment2();
    return fragment;
}
```

and so on if else what ever your require implements and override for this method,

```
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
            return ;
        case 1: 
            return ;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

try it out.

Comment: I didn't get you. I want to get a particular Fragment used by a Tab. using any of the two methods: **findFragmentByTag** or **findFragmentById**. So where do i set them initially when adding the tabs to the FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: override for this two methods and implements for logical code

Comment: You mean: instead of **findFragmentByTag** or **findFragmentById** use **PagerAdapter.getItem(position)** to get the corresponding Fragment??

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what the adapter does when looking for the fragment at position x  EDIT: btw, your current getItem method creates a new fragment every time it get's called. Cache them in a class/instance variable.